# How to use numpy.random.choice in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to do a random choice with a given probability for selecting a tuple from a list.

EDIT:
The probabiliy for each tuple is in probabilit list
I do not know forget the parameter replacement, by default is none
The same problem using an array instead a list

The next sample code give me an error:

```
import numpy as np

probabilit = [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]
lista_elegir = [(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)]

np.random.choice(lista_elegir, 1, probabilit)
```

And the error is:

```
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

How can i solve that?

Comment: If you just want to draw elements with equal probability, you can use `random.choice` from the standard lib.

Comment: I have the wrong numpy version so I can not test, but according to [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice), have you tried making the list a numpy `array`? Also, it seems like you are missing the third parameter `replace`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the function's doc,

```
a : 1-D array-like or int
    If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements.
    If an int, the random sample is generated as if a was np.arange(n)
```

So following that

```
lista_elegir[np.random.choice(len(lista_elegir),1,p=probabilit)]
```

should do what you want.  (`p=` added as per comment; can omit if values are uniform).

It is choosing a number from [0,1,2], and then picking that element from your list.

Comment: In Python 3.6 the above gives me an error when sampling more than one item: `only integer scaler arrays can be converted to a scaler index`. This is not resolved by casting to `int` or using `range(len(x))` instead of `len(x)`. One solution is to a use an inline for loop: `[x[i] for i in np.choice(len(x), n)]` works fine

Comment: @Scipio this happens because `lista_elegir` is a list. Use `np.asarray(lista_elegir)` to acess by index.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the list of tuples is interpreted as a 2D-array, while `choice` only works with 1D-arrays or integers (interpreted as "choose from range"). See [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice).

So one way to fix this is to pass the `len` of the list of tuples, and then pick the elements with the respective index (or indices), as described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821364/1639625). If you turn `lista_elegir` into a `np.array` first, this will also work for multiple indices. However, there are two more problems:

First, the way you invoke the function, `probabilit` will be interpreted as the *third* parameter, `replace`, *not* as the probabilities, i.e., the list is interpreted as a boolean, meaning that you choose with replacement, but the actual probabilities are ignored. You can easily check this by passing the third parameter as `[1, 0, 0]`. Use `p=probabilit` instead. Second, the probabilities have to sum up to 1, *exactly*. Yours are only `0.999`. It seems you will have to skew the probabilities slighty, or just leave that parameter as `None` if they are all the same (thus assuming uniform distribution).

```
>>> probabilit = [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]
>>> lista_elegir = np.array([(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)]) # for multiple indices
>>> indices = np.random.choice(len(lista_elegir), 2, p=probabilit if len(set(probabilit)) > 1 else None)
>>> lista_elegir[indices]
array([[3, 4],
       [3, 5]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just using rundom

```
import random
import numpy as np

DIRECTIONS = [np.array([-1, 0]),
          np.array([0, 1]),
          np.array([1, 0]),
          np.array([0, -1])]

random.choice(DIRECTIONS)
```

as result got one of the tuples

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is very old, but leaving this here just in case anyone else ends up here.

A thing that worked for me is to convert the list to an nparray. You can always convert it back to list later.

```
import numpy as np

numSamples = 2    
probabilit = [0.333, 0.333, 0.333] 
lista_elegir = [(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)]

lista_elegir_arr = np.array(lista_elegir)

#make sure probabilities sum to 1, and if they are all the same they are not needed
np.random.choice(lista_elegir_arr, numSamples, p = None)
```

Comment: Notice that when you convert back, it will be a list of lists, not a list of tuples. You will also have to do that second step of converting

Comment: I ran the snippet and it gives the same error: "ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: Also got the ValueError for np.__version__ = 1.19.2

Answer (score 2):

## a short & simple solution in plain English

`numpy` version 1.19.2

```
import numpy as np

probs = [.1, .2, .7]
vals = [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
n_samples = 5  # choose so may elements from vals

np.random.seed(1)  # fix random seed for reproducibility
inds = np.random.choice(len(vals), n_samples, p=probs)
rand_vals = [vals[ind] for ind in inds]
print(rand_vals)
```

**output**

```
[(3, 2), (3, 2), (3, 0), (3, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: ran into the same problem.. I think the code in the o.p. should work. Is it fair to say that Numpy implementation is not generic (pythonic??) in the sense that a list is a list (1D), even if the elements inside it are not scalars. The code in the o.p. would have worked fine if the list element were scalars.. why would Numpy implementation not allow for this?